# Are /news and /news/ two different pages?

Tags: redirect, seo, google-analytics, analytics

Just been looking through my Google analytics and have found two entries for the news section

```
/news/    =     150 page views

/news     =     127 page views
```

This is for the site [greatlearning](http://www.greatlearning.com/ipc/news/)

Should I ask our web developer to redirect `/news` to `/news/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put in the redirect if `/news` and `/news/` are guaranteed to have the same content. They are technically different URLs, so they'll both show up in indexes, caches, statistics, etc.

Comment: ok interesting... do you think I should make the /news/ standard?

Comment: I believe that's the more common choice. I'm not sure if there's a technical reason for preferring the trailing slash, though.

Comment: @TheoG - The same goes for "www.your-domain.com" and "your-domain.com"

Answer (score 0):

Iarsmans is correct - the trailing slash is default.  However, from an SEO standpoint, you want to redirect the page with less links to the page with more links to preserve 'link juice'.  You can check the number of inbound links going to a specific page via opensiteexplorer.org or ahrefs.com

Answer (score -1):

i don't think so because the ending slash doesn't matter in url.

Comment: thanks for your reply Subash... when you say it doesn't matter, do you mean it wont be treated as a duplicate page?

Comment: @Subash, can you provide a reference for this assertion?